# How to give an employee a raise using arrays and loops

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I need some help.  I created a constant for a small company initialize to 5. I declared an array to hold unique salaries and declared a variable to hold a raise. However I am struggling with using loops to give each salary in the array the raise the user received and then use another loop to display the new salary amounts with the format specifier. Below is the code I am trying to put together.

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    const int NumOfSalaries = 5;
    int[] UniqueSalary = {30000,40000,50000,55000,60000};
    decimal raise = 0.0M;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a raise amount");
    raise = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    foreach (int number in UniqueSalary)
      raise += number;

    foreach (int number in UniqueSalary)
      Console.WriteLine(" {0}", UniqueSalary);


  } // end Main
} // end class
```

Comment: Use for loop and index to alter array value

Comment: Look more carefully at which variables you use--you're increasing the `raise` by each `number` in `UniqueSalary` and printing out `UniqueSalary` for each `number` in `UniqueSalary`! Better naming might help: change `UniqueSalary` to `UniqueSalaries` to match the plural nature of the array, and use `int salary` instead of `int number` in your `foreach`es. Then you hit the main problem: that you can't use `foreach` to *change* a number inside an array.

Comment: You're adding `number` (the salary) to `raise`. You're incrementing `raise`, not the person's salary. Switch those two variables, and then convert it to a `for` loop because you can't modify the contents of a collection from within a `foreach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a for loop and assign the raise to each element of the array as shown below.

```
decimal[] UniqueSalary = { 30000, 40000, 50000, 55000, 60000 };
        decimal raise = 0.0M;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a raise amount");
        raise = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < UniqueSalary.Length; i++)
            UniqueSalary[i] += raise;

        for(int i = 0; i < UniqueSalary.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(" {0}", UniqueSalary[i]);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Note: I have changed the array type from an int to decimal. You could maintain an int array and do a conversion when adding the raise.

Comment: Can you explain to me what is happening in the for loop? I don't know if you can break it down Barney style for me.

Comment: @Dell I am looping through each element of the array UniqueSalary using the index i and incrementing the salary stored in this array. You can read more on the basics of this here http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/loops/

Comment: thank you so much. I will check out the link.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is inside your for loop.

```
foreach (int number in UniqueSalary)
  raise += number;
```

This is adding the variable `number` to the `raise` and storing it back in `raise`. You need to store it in the array instead.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I can't apply the "=+" operator to operands of type "int[]"